# Report Builder 3.0 How to filter on different columns

Tags: sql, filter, reportbuilder3.0

I have a parameter in my report (Report Builder 3.0) called REPORT_FILTER.  This parameter has 4 available values.  The labels are (1) Home Group, (2) Home Branch, (3) Other Group, and (4) Other Branch.  The corresponding values are 1, 2, 3, and 4.

The SQL used to run this report adds "1" to the "Filter1" column for the Home Group and "2" to the "Filter1" column for the Other Group.

The SQL used to run this report adds "1" to the "Filter2" column for the Home Branch and "2" to the "Filter2" column for the Other Branch.

When the SQL runs, I get 1 or 2 in the "Filter 1" and "Filter 2" columns. This data is just what I expect.

What I would like to do is add a filter to the report so the user only gets the records they want.  What I'm struggling with is that the filter(s) will have to use 2 columns and I'm not sure how to do that.

For example, if the user selects, Home Group (value = 1), the report should only return those records that have a 1 in the Filter1 column

If the user selects, Other Branch (value = 4), the report should only return those records that have a 2 in the Filter2 column

This report already takes a while to run several minutes, so (I think) I would prefer to filter the results in Report Builder instead of with the SQL.  If I could do it with SQL, that would be acceptable.  I've tried to write SQL to do this but haven't been able to succeed as well.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to do in SQL, just add this WHERE condition:

```
WHERE 
CASE 
WHEN
   @REPORT_FILTER = 4 and Filter2 = 2 then 1
WHEN
   @REPORT_FILTER = 3 and Filter2 = 1 then 1
WHEN
   @REPORT_FILTER = 2 and Filter1 = 2 then 1
WHEN
   @REPORT_FILTER = 1 and Filter1 = 1 then 1
ELSE 0
END = 1
```

And similarly in SSRS, just use a Filters expression of

```
(Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 4 And Fields!Filter2.Value = 2)
OR
(Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 3 And Fields!Filter2.Value = 1)
OR
(Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 2 And Fields!Filter1.Value = 2)
OR
(Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 1 And Fields!Filter1.Value = 1)
```

Set the expression type to Boolean and set the comparison value to True.

[image]

Comment: .....Thanks for the suggestions.  I'm going to try them this afternoon.  I really appreciate the detailed information

Comment: @Kyle_Hale.......I'm adding another filter called "All".  How do I add that to the SSRS example.  The value will be 5 and should include all records.  I tried "OR (Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 5 And Fields!Filter1.Value = 1 And Fields!Filter1.Value = 2).  Thanks for the help

Comment: If you want 5 just add (OR Parameter!Report_FILTER.Value = 5) by itself, no other filters neede.

Comment: @Kyle_Hale..........Thanks.........I've added the filter through the Tablix properties.  When I run the report, it returns all records.  I'm trying to use the filter to present different views / subsets of the report results.  If I change the filter parameter and hit the "view report" button a again, will it display the subset I'm looking for?  My users will want to run the report and then look at the results in different ways.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes? If they choose REPORT_FILTER value of 1, this will only show rows where Filter1 equals 1.

Comment: Thanks but the expression is not working for me.  No matter what filter selection I make , the results are always the same

Comment: Sorry, it's working for me? Here's a sample RDL: http://pastebin.com/aTLj69xC you just need to change the Data Set's connection string to point to a valid SQL Server instance. My rough guess is your parameter isn't doing what you think it's doing.